# Get Child Node XML With DomDocument PHP

Tags: php

I have read instruction of DomDocument PHP, and try to get specific child from xml file, here the example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <methods>
        <index>
            <title>User</title>
            <meta_description>Description part</meta_description>
            <meta_keywords>keywords parts</meta_keywords>
            <permissions>permissions part</permissions>
            <layout>layout parts</layout>
            <css>css parts</css>
        </index>
        <update>
            <title>update part</title>
            <permissions>update_user</permissions>
        </update>
    </methods>
</configuration>
```

What I want is, let say I want to access permissions value tag of index tag, then how to do that? And how to check if permissions tag is exists on index tag with domdocument php.

Here, what I have done

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();
    $xml->load(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'configuration.xml');
    $configurations['title'] = $xml->getElementsByTagName('index title')->nodeValue;
    print_r($configurations);
```

Comment: Can you provide your current PHP that you've attempted? Because what you want to do is very straightforward (the documentation for DOMDocument literally gives you the code for this task).

Comment: @Marty sure, I had give the snippet code of php.

Comment: That look almost correct, I think you want `$xml->getElementsByTagName('index')->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('title')->textValue` or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

The argument of `DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName()` is a single node name and it always returns a node list. For more complex and flexible expressions you need to use XPath:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'configuration.xml');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$configurations['title'] = $xpath->evaluate('string(//index/title)');
var_dump($configurations);
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  ["title"]=>
  string(4) "User"
}
```